# Webfont diacritical characters broken?

Tags: css, webfonts

on a webpage I use the OpenSans webfont, which should be capable of diacritical characters of croatian language e.g. "Š" and "Č".
My problem: **only** diacritical characters sting out **inside a word**, while it doesn't matter if I use regular font with font-weight bold or if I use OpenSans-700 with font-weight bold or normal. For example:

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

prints the word "ABCČXYŠPQ" correctly with bold characters within HTML anchor-tags, but "Š" and "Č" are a little bit bolder and/or darker - this two chars sting out from the other chars.

Is there some CSS to handle this?

P.S.: just seen the other way round, also: everything is bold, but diacritical chars are regular within words inside HTML-p-tags!? What's wrong?

---

**EDIT: ADDING A DEMO FOR US TO FIGURE OUT THE ISSUE**

```css
body {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.section-title {
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.s-weight400 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.s-weight700 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.os-weight400 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.os-weight700 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='section-title'>SANS SERIF:</div>
    <div class="s-weight400">ABCČXYŠPQ</div>
    <div class="s-weight700">ABCČXYŠPQ</div>
    <div class='section-title'>OPEN SANS:</div>
    <div class="os-weight400">ABCČXYŠPQ</div>
    <div class="os-weight700">ABCČXYŠPQ</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created a code snippet in your post while attempting to recreate your issue, and I'm not seeing what you describe. Is there other `CSS` in your project that could potentially be impacting this?

Comment: I also do not see the issue. I edited your question to add a demo as close as I could figure from your question. Please feel free to edit to be more exact.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you all for answering to my question.

I was able to figure out, now: since I host the webfont on my own server, I missed to include some font-extensions from Googles' webfont helper. After adding this cyrillic-ext extensions the font is displayed correctly.

This was my own fault - and your snippet pointed me to the correct solution, thank you!